# How are two proportionalities put together?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mathematics

In a lot of mechanics equations, such as F=ma, we say that "F" is proportional to "a" and "F" is proportional to "m", therefore "F" is proportional to "m x a". Is there a mathematical reasoning for why if something is proportional to two or more things, it is proportional to the multiplication of these factors? I have seen some answers on other sites which say you need to know calculus to understand it, but I don't, and it seems there should be a simpler way. Is there any proof, or is it just reasoning. If so, what is the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a quantity $F$ that is a function of, for example, variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ (though this same argument works for any number of variables). Formally, we notate this function as $F(a,b,c)$.

Now suppose that we know that $F$ is proportional to $a$. What this means is that $F$ takes the following form:

$$F(a,b,c)=K(b,c)a$$

where $K(b,c)$ is the "proportionality constant," which is only actually a constant when we also hold $b$ and $c$ to be constant. This is the general definition of proportionality.

If we also know that $F$ is proportional to $b$, then we can write a similar expression:

$$F(a,b,c)=D(a,c)b$$

for some proportionality constant $D(a,c)$.

We can equate the two definitions of $F$:

$$K(b,c)a=D(a,c)b$$

If we set $c=0$ in the above (or to any constant value, really), we find:

$$K(b,0)a=D(a,0)b$$

At this point, it should be clear that the only expressions that could make the left and right sides equal for arbitrary $a$ and $b$ are either

$$K(b,0)=D(a,0)=0$$

or

$$K(b,0)=Qb\quad\mathrm{and}\quad D(a,0)=Qa$$

for some (nonzero) constant $Q$.

If we set both $K$ and $D$ to zero, then $F(a,b,c)=0$. Assuming that $F$ is nonzero, our only option is the second assignment, so:

$$F(a,b,0)=Qab$$.

If we again allow $c$ to vary, we must also allow $Q$ to vary as a function of $c$, so

$$F(a,b,c)=Q(c)ab$$

which shows that $F$ is proportional to $ab$.